# Regarding the differences in VBA Match and Excel match

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problems with this code

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Template").Cells(5, 2), Worksheets("Japan1").Rows(2), 0)
```

As you can tell, this is a Match Function. I tried using the excel version of match on the same set of cells with absolutely no problem.

However, I have the error with VBA, 1004, unable to find match property.

I suspect that it requires me to declare something because if I had set the criteria to 1. It returns a result that is not ideal (and not the same as the one I managed to pull with excel alone)

Thank you for the trouble!

Comment: try `Application.Match(Worksheets("Template").Cells(5, 2).Value, Worksheets("Japan1").Rows(2), 0)`